# savefig() not saving anything into folder

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am unable to solve an issue that I am currently facing. I am trying to save my Matplotlib histogram figure inside a Databricks File System (DBFS) folder. However, it doesn't seem to be working as upon checking the folder, there is no image file. I used a similar code for another time-series plot, but that plot is able to be saved in the folder. I hope someone is able to help me as I have searched online to no avail.

Below is the code that works by using an 'if' condition such that the plots for each column is created.

Another thing is that the bottom of the figure has a number of subplots that are empty, I am not sure if this could be the cause of the issue.

[Image of empty plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ1oH.png)

```
ncols = 3
nrows = int(np.ceil(len(df.columns) / ncols))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(20, 170))


counter = 0
for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(ncols):

        ax = axes[i][j]
        if counter < len(df.columns):

            ax.hist(df[df.columns[counter]], bins=20, color='blue', alpha=0.5, label='{}'.format(df.columns[counter]))

            leg = ax.legend(loc='upper left')
            leg.draw_frame(False)

        else:
            ax.set_axis_off()

        counter += 1

# Directory shown here is not actual directory, but I know that it works as it is working for another type of plot (time-series)

plt.savefig("/dbfs/folder/histogram_plots.png")
```

Comment: I was able to create a histogram with the sample data and save it locally, the image shows the histogram. You have access to the folder you want to save it in, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I also had issues with savefig in databricks. Using fig to .savefig as follows helped me. Using a recent version of dbx cluster (such as 7.4) may also help

```
fig.savefig("/dbfs/folder/histogram_plots.png")
```

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work for me. Thanks for the suggestion though, hope it can help others.